# Change my post to a JSON Array in Flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

I am very new to Flutter, and programming as a whole, and am looking for some help. I have some code which currently posts in JSON correctly, but I want it to post as an array instead and I am not really sure on how to do that.

I have seen and tried a few different solutions, but am unsure exactly how to implement them into my code to make them work.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'contact.dart';

class ContactService {
 static const _serviceUrl = 'https://******.com/';
  static final _headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

  Future<Contact> createContact(Contact contact) async {
    try {
      String json = _toJson(contact);
      final response =
      await http.post(_serviceUrl, headers: _headers, body: json);
      var c = _fromJson(response.body);
      return c;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Server Exception!!!');
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  Contact _fromJson(String json) {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(json);
    var contact = new Contact();
    contact.firstName = map['First Name'];
    contact.lastName = map ['Last Name'];
    contact.dob = new DateFormat.yMd().parseStrict(map['dob']);
    contact.phone = map['phone'];
    contact.email = map['email'];
    contact.gender = map['gender'];
    return contact;
  }

  String _toJson(Contact contact) {
    var mapData = new Map();
    mapData["first_name"] = contact.firstName;
    mapData["last_name"] = contact.lastName;
    mapData["dob"] = new DateFormat.yMd().format(contact.dob);
    mapData["phone"] = contact.phone;
    mapData["email"] = contact.email;
    mapData["gender"] = contact.gender;
    String json = jsonEncode(mapData);
    return json;
  }
}
```

Other lib file (contact.dart):

```
class Contact {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  DateTime dob;
  String phone = '';
  String email = '';
  String gender = '';
```

I would like it to post to my URL as a JSON Array rather than just a line of JSON code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make it appear in array form.

```
json = '['+ json +']';
```

I added this line of code in right before the last line of code. Doing this added the square brackets I needed in order for the back-end to receive it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `List` instead of a Map then use the `dart:convert` package as below.

```
import 'dart:convert';

final List<String> data = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
final String jsonData = json.encode(data);
print(jsonData);
```

Comment: I'm really new to this I apologize, so where exactly would I make that change and how? Would I replace every instance of the word "map"? And how would I rewrite my contact that I am trying to post? I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that to my code and still pull the form data I am trying to post.